# How to add a reset password to MVC4 Controller App

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am trying to add a reset password using the Entity framework. I cannot get the Login view to link to my Manage View were I have my password reset form. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? When I click on the Forgot password link it is defaulting to the main login page and cannot seem to figure out why. It is working fine for my Register link to the Register view. In my Account controller I have the two HTTP Posts to "[AllowAnonymous]".

```
@model ComtrexCloudReporting.Models.LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}



<section id="loginForm">
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "Manage") 
    </p>

}
</section>
```

Here is what I have for my manage view:

```
@using ComtrexCloudReporting.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Account";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<p class="text-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @if (ViewBag.HasLocalPassword)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Partial("_SetPasswordPartial")
        }

        <section id="externalLogins">
            @Html.Action("RemoveAccountList")
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new { Action = 

"LinkLogin", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
        {
            ManageMessageId? message = null;
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
            }
            else
            {
                message = ManageMessageId.Error;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage
        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
        {
            bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasPassword)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {


 // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I am now getting an error when I click forgot password in this part of the controller... for

```
private bool HasPassword()
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user.PasswordHash != null;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

It says user cannot be null both when the user name is in and when it is not. here is the rest of the action:

```
   // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveAccountList()
        {
            var linkedAccounts = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = HasPassword() || linkedAccounts.Count > 1;
            return (ActionResult)PartialView("_RemoveAccountPartial", linkedAccounts);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && UserManager != null)
            {
                UserManager.Dispose();
                UserManager = null;
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Helpers
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
        }

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        private bool HasPassword()
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user.PasswordHash != null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
            Error
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
        {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri) : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
            {
            }

            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
            {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                UserId = userId;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
                }
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: authentication has nothing to do with the entity framework :-)

Comment: Where's your controller code?  From what controller and action are you rendering that login view?  What is the resulting link that gets generated for the "forgot password" link?  What controller action is it invoking?  What does that action do?  There's a lot here you're not showing us.

Comment: If you have `[authorize]` on the reset action then the User is at a dead end...  We need to see the Controller.

Comment: I just meant that those are the default settings I am using with my project.

Comment: Posted the Controller

Comment: @david The link is http://localhost:55088/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fManage

Comment: @David but I want the link to be: http://localhost:55088/Account/Manage

Comment: @MeganMeluskey: One of your controller actions has `[AllowAnonymous]`, whereas the `Manage` GET action does not.  This implies that the `Manage` action requires the user to be logged in.  Is the user logged in?  If they're currently on a login form then that implies they are not.  If the user is not logged in and they try to access a restricted resource then I would expect them to be redirected to a login page.  Did you just forget to put `[AllowAnonymous]` on the `Manage` GET action?

Comment: @David thank you, I put the that above the Get action. However it gave me an error on this line:                       
 var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()); it is in a different action of the controller I am going to post now. Thanks for your help

Comment: @David I just posted the rest of the controller

Comment: @MeganMeluskey: What is the exact exception and stack trace, and what exact operation is throwing the exception?  I wouldn't expect to be able to get the user ID or find the user when the user *isn't logged in*.

Comment: Its the one that says GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure and the Action: RemoveAccountList()

Comment: The error that I am getting is:   Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: userId
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: userId
Line 444:        private bool HasPassword()
Line 445:        {
Line 446:            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
Line 447:            if (user != null)
Line 448:            {

Comment: @David this is what the top part of the stack trace is saying [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: userId]

Comment: @MeganMeluskey: Seems pretty straightforward then.  When a user is not logged in, they don't have an ID.  So you can't find the user for a null ID.  You could make use of (I think) `User.IsAuthenticated` (check your intellisense in Visual Studio to find the exact property) to see if the user is authenticated before trying to find information about the authenticated user.

Comment: Expanding on @David's comment, it seems that in `UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId())` the `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method can not find an identity and thus no ID for `User`. `User` in this case refers to the logged in user.